# I'm trying to save the contacts on local storage and retrieve them, but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to save my contacts on the local storage and also retrieve them, but its not working

Here is the code i used. What could be missing?

```
useEffect(()=> {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY , JSON.stringify(contacts))
  }, [contacts])

  useEffect(()=> {
    const retrievedContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
    if(retrievedContacts) setContacts(retrievedContacts)
  }, [])
```

for better clarification here is my github link to the project : https://github.com/AirSayy/Contact-card-app

Comment: Can u give more information?

Where should the contacts come from in the first place?

The second useEffect works only then component is mounted.(localStorage is empty) so code inside the if block doest work, therefore, the 1st useEffect does not work and nothing is written to localstorage

Comment: can you please elaborate the error or exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: Can it be that the `contacts` are empty when the component renders initially, which overwrites the existing contacts in localStorage? Does it help when you wrap the storing in a condition? `if (contacts) { localStorage.setItem(...) }`

Comment: When i refresh , it returns the empty array from the localStroage.getItem()

Answer (score 0):

This code alone will not work, you will need a listener which listens to localstorage on that particular key.

The following code works fine for me:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify({ contact: "contact" }));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const retrievedContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key"));
    if (retrievedContacts) setContacts(retrievedContacts);
  }, []);

  return <div>{contacts?.contact}</div>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the localStorage.setItem already saves the contact on localStorage but on page refresh it disappears so the getItem function doesn't work.